# Spring Reactor | Batching the input without mutating

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm trying to batch the records constantly emitted from a streaming source (Kafka) and call my service in a batch of 100.

What I get as the input is a single record. I'm trying what's the best way to achieve it in the Reactive way using Spring Reactor without having to have a mutation and locking outside the pipeline.

Here is my naive attempt which simply reflects my sequential way of thinking:

```
 Mono.just(input)
                .subscribe(i -> {
                     batches.add(input);
                     if(batches.size() >= 100) {
                         // Invoke another reactive pipeline.
                         // Clear the batch (requires locking in order to be thread safe).
                     }
                });
```

What's the best way to achieve batching on a streaming source using reactor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## `.buffer(100)` or `bufferTimeout(100, Duration.ofSeconds(xxx)` comes to the rescue

Using `Flux.buffer` or `Flux.bufferTimeout` you will be capable of gathering the fixed amount of elements into the `List`

```
StepVerifier.create(
      Flux.range(0, 1000)
          .buffer(100)
   )
   .expectNextCount(10)
   .expectComplete()
   .verify()
```

## Update for the use case

In case, when the input is a single value, suppose like an invocation of the method with parameter:

```
public void invokeMe(String element);
```

You may adopt `UnicastProcessor` technique and transfer all data to that processor so then it will take care of batching

```
class Batcher {

   final UnicastProcessor processor = UnicastProcessor.create();

   public void invokeMe(String element) {
       processor.sink().next(element);
       // or Mono.just(element).subscribe(processor);
   }


   public Flux<List<String>> listen() {
       return processor.bufferTimeout(100, Duration.ofSeconds(5));
   }
}

Batcher batcher = new Batcher();

StepVerifier.create(
      batcher.listen()
   )
   .then(() -> Flux.range(0, 1000)
                   .subscribe(i -> batcher.invokeMe("" + i)))
   .expectNextCount(10)
   .thenCancel()
   .verify()
```

From that example, we might learn how to provide a single point of receiving events and then listen to results of the batching process.

> **Please note** that `UnicastPorcessor` allows only one subscriber, so it will be useful for the model when there is one interested party in batching results and many data producers. In a case when you have subscribers as many as producers you may want to use one of the next processors -> `DirectProcessor`, `TopicProcessor`, `WorkerQueueProcessor`. To learn more about Reactor Processors follow the [link](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/snapshot/reference/#processor-overview)

Comment: ok - But in my case, I get the input as an argument to the method as a single value. For ex: `void onMessage(String input) { // Reactive batching goes on here. }` As far as the call to every method is concerned, it's a stateless call. Where would I keep track of the batch state here?